# CSS - :target ~

Tags: css, css-selectors

That´s my html code:

```
<a href="#anchor">test</a>
<ul id="anchor"></ul>
```

Now I want to style my target, which isn´t a problem.

```
#anchor:target 
{
}
```

But I want to select the sibling of the target (a).

```
#anchor:target ~ a{
    background: blue;
}
```

It´s not working. How to select the sibling of the target?

Comment: Are you trying to get the `a` *before* the `ul`? That wont work with the sibling selector. It only selects siblings *after* the element. You would need to change the order of your markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to style the previous siblings with CSS. To achieve this, you'll have to use javascript.

You can get the next sibling with `+` or all `<a>`s after your `<ul>` with `~`:

```
#anchor:target + a {
    /*

    <ul></ul>
    <a>will get this one</a>
    <a>but not this one</a>

    */
}

#anchor:target ~ a {
    /*

    <ul></ul>
    <a>will get this one</a>
    <a>and this one too!</a>

    */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS there is no "previous" sibling selector (in CSS2 or CSS3).

The "Selectors Level 4" draft introduces the **!** selector, which if I understand it correctly, allows for previous sibling selection.
https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#subject

However, this is still in draft form, and is far from being supported in all the major browsers.

Sorry, but it's not possible with the current CSS spec.
The only way to really achieve this would be to use JavaScript, or to change the order of your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you cannot get previous siblings. But you can select a element with specific attribute like this:

```css
a[href="#anchor"] {
 color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<a href="#anchor">test</a>
<ul id="anchor"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

as per my previous answer, this isn't possible in the way you've written due to limitations in CSS.

However, you could always match the  itself?

```
a[target|="#"] {
}
```

This would select all `<a>` tags within your document that point to local anchors.